# ASP.NET Check if application has access to folder

Tags: asp.net

How can I check from an ASP.NET application if it has access to a folder?

For example, I have a code that checks if a file is in a folder, as follows:

```
if (!File.Exists( strFolderName + strFileName ))
```

The code above does not find the file even if file does exist, if the account that the application impersonates (in Web.Config) has no full access to folder strFolderName.  Thus I need to, first, check if the application has access to the folder.  But how?

Comment: Actually before you do that, can you verify the path above (is correct)? Then look into things like giving the [app identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) appropriate permissions. Hth...

Comment: @EdSF  I know that the path is correct.  But the main point is that you cannot foresee the folder(s) that user will decide to "look into". So my question still stands as to how to find if the user identity allow access to this or that folder.

Comment: IMHO, it's the other way around re: `I need to, first, check if the application has access to the folder`. **You** set up what the `ASP.NET` application "user" has access to. In other words, its already "known". Even in `impersonation` that (specific) user's privileges should already be known/confined/restricted/pre-configured. I guess context is missing - though it's still questionable what kind of server file system/directory traversal one would expect to expose in `asp.net` (security).

Comment: @EdSF I agree that it is a good idea to check what privileges the impersonated user account has (to this or that folder).  I suppose my question was more academic/basic; would it be possible to check the privileges to a folder from the application.  From your input and silence of others I see that maybe it is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly - see [MSDN FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx). Do tread carefully. Hth...

Comment: @EdSF  Thank you I will follow the link.